# bitsPerPixel gives wrong value

Tags: objective-c, image, memory-management, pixel, cgimageref

I'm confused about image resolution. In my project `sizeof` returns 4. It means that between one and the next pixel address is a 4 bytes. In other words i have RGBA format, 1 byte for each component? is it right? When i call `CGImageGetBitsPerComponent` i get 8 bits (1 byte for component). But when i call `CGImageGetBitsPerPixel` i get 8 bits. Why? I thought `bitsPerPixel = (count of components) * bitsPerComponent` and this is equal to 4 bytes. How do I get 8 bits instead of 4 bytes? Please tell me someone. Thanks

Comment: `sizeof WHAT` returns 4?

Comment: I understand that the result is 4 bytes, but I asked you WHAT you measured the `sizeof`. You didn't do `print("%i", sizeof(elephant))`, did you? WHAT did you measure the size of?

Comment: I didn't ask this. I don't understand why are the bitsForComponent equal 8 bits and bitsPerPixel have the same value. There are 4 components.